# abstract syntax tree (AST) scan

Tags: go, casting, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm trying to **extract function calls from go AST**:

```
$ cat main.go
package main
import ("fmt"; "go/ast"; "go/token"; "go/parser"; "io/ioutil")

func CalledFuncs(n ast.Node) bool {
    switch n.(type) {
    case *ast.CallExpr:
        l := ast.CallExpr(n).Lparen
        r := ast.CallExpr(n).Right
        fmt.Printf("call %d( ... %d)\n",l,r)
    }
    return true
}

func main() {
    fset := token.NewFileSet()
    src,_ := ioutil.ReadFile("simple.go")
    f, _ := parser.ParseFile(fset,">>",src,0)
    ast.Inspect(f, CalledFuncs)
}
```

But the go compiler complains I can't do the casting:

```
$ go build -o main main.go
# command-line-arguments
./main.go:7:26: cannot convert n (type ast.Node) to type ast.CallExpr
./main.go:8:26: cannot convert n (type ast.Node) to type ast.CallExpr
```

I'm probably missing something here.

Comment: The compiler is correct, you can't convert an interface to a concrete type, even if the concrete type is the dynamic type of the interface variable. You might want to brush up on https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions and https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_switches. Here's what you probably should be doing: https://play.golang.org/p/Ulj9I-P5da2

Comment: @OrenIshShalom: this is very basic Go. Any good tutorial *must* cover this when it covers interfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_switches

> The `TypeSwitchGuard` may include a [short variable declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations). When
> that form is used, the variable is declared at the end of the
> `TypeSwitchCase` in the [implicit block](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Blocks) of each clause. In clauses with a
> case listing exactly one type, the variable has that type; otherwise,
> the variable has the type of the expression in the `TypeSwitchGuard`.

That means that you can do the following:

```golang
func CalledFuncs(n ast.Node) bool {
    switch x := n.(type) {
    case *ast.CallExpr:
        l := x.Lparen
        r := x.Rparen
        fmt.Printf("call %d( ... %d)\n", l, r)
    }
    return true
}
```